# CSS: Items at the bottom of parent element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can override `align-items: flex-start` with `align-self: flex-end` for a specific flex item, is there any way to override justify-content for a 
 specific flex item?

I have a box with three child items and I need the last item (`item-3`) at the bottom of my box (`flex_wrapper`)

**like this image:** 
[image]

Check my code please:

```css
.item-1{
  background: red;
}

.item-2{
  background: blue;
}

.item-3{
  background: yellow;
}


.flex_wrapper{
  background: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex_items{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_wrapper">
    <div class="flex_items item-1">Item 01</div>
    <div class="flex_items item-2">Item 02</div>
    <div class="flex_items item-3">Item 03</div>
</div>
```

> Note: It is possible by using margin property or position property,
>   but I have to use flex-box.

Comment: why not margin-top:auto ? it's also flexbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is actually very simple, just give the element you want at the bottom `margin-top:auto`. No wrappers or extra elements required.

```
.item-3{

  margin-top:auto;
}
```

```css
.item-1 {
  background: red;
}

.item-2 {
  background: blue;
}

.item-3 {
  background: yellow;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.flex_wrapper {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex_items {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_wrapper">
  <div class="flex_items item-1">Item 01</div>
  <div class="flex_items item-2">Item 02</div>
  <div class="flex_items item-3">Item 03</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an invisible item in between with `flex-grow: 1` to occupy the space and push your 3rd item down:

```css
.item-1{
  background: red;
}

.item-2{
  background: blue;
}

.item-3{
  background: yellow;
}


.flex_wrapper{
  background: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex_items{
  padding: 10px;
}

.separator {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_wrapper">
    <div class="flex_items item-1">Item 01</div>
    <div class="flex_items item-2">Item 02</div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <div class="flex_items item-3">Item 03</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @DelowarHosain No Sir! `margin-top: 0` is just fine to use, grid can do that, but not flex, which is _1-dimensional system_

Comment: If you only had 2 items it would be possible by using `justify-content: space-between;` but not once you have more than 2